# Set ApplePressAndHoldEnabled for one specific application

Tags: intellij-idea, macos-mojave

I came across these questions : [Intellij-idea: auto-repetition of letter keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15107321/intellij-idea-auto-repetition-of-letter-keys) and [IntelliJ key repeating idea.vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39606031/intellij-key-repeating-idea-vim). Both explain that you can be more specific and modify the behavior of only IntelliJ or any application by specifying the CFBundleIdentifier and the -g option of the above solution changes it for all applications.

Although the global solution (with the '-g' instead of de CFBundleIdentifier of a specific application) works perfectly (it activates Key Repeat in all applications). This option can not be set at the application level.

I have typed the following things and it seems ok but does not work when restarting the application (in my case intelliJ) or rebooting the system.

```
defaults write com.jetbrains.intellij ApplePressAndHoldEnabled -bool false
```

This command returned '0'.

```
defaults read com.jetbrains.intellij ApplePressAndHoldEnabled
```

And this command returned 'Type is boolean' as it should.

```
defaults read-type com.jetbrains.intellij ApplePressAndHoldEnabled
```

According to these results it should only work on the application identified by com.jetbrains.intellij, but it didn't.

I'm running MacOS Mojave (10.14.3).

Comment: See the canonical, complete solution to this problem, here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70911250/14193

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a solution thanks to this guy and his message [Characters don't repeat when ApplePressAndHoldEnabled is disabled for VSCode](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/31919#issuecomment-343897993). I'm so grateful.

> I think I've found the solution for this. It looks like, if you've set `ApplePressAndHoldEnabled` at a global level (i.e. `defaults write -g ApplePressAndHoldEnabled -bool true`), this will override app-level preferences.
>
> My solution was to reset that global with `defaults delete -g ApplePressAndHoldEnabled`, ensure the VSCode has an app-level pref disabling PressAndHold (`defaults write com.microsoft.VSCode ApplePressAndHoldEnabled -bool false`), and to then restart VSCode. Now works exactly as expected (and PressAndHold still works in other apps which I haven't turned it off for).

Comment: See the canonical, complete solution to this problem, here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70911250/14193